# We would like to get a recommendation for an API. Which stackexchange site to use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We are searching for an API that lets you create your own deals for your own mobile app. Seems stackoverflow might be aware of it but still is not a software question. Which stack exchange site is the most appropriate?
Thank you

Comment: It is not software, we are looking for API

Comment: Yet the answer is the same. Recommendations are generally off-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange, with SoftwareRecs being the only exception. Consider the site an experiment in how Stack Exchange can cater for a need to recommendations.