# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can get a recommendation for an API?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I ask on Stack Overflow (*[What are someways way to get direct links to mp3s of songs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268115/what-are-someways-way-to-get-direct-links-to-mp3s-of-songs)*) and I get downvoted and no response.

I ask on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) and get told that it's about finding web applications, not developing them.

Is there a place I can go to simply get a recommendation as to an API or service to get MP3 files for songs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We would like to get a recommendation for an API. Which stackexchange site to use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226945/) which itself is a dupe of [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411/398063)